# Stop a sprite accurately at destination using vectors

Tags: graphics, vector, cocos2d-iphone

I want my sprite to move to a precise pixel location. I use the following code in the update method to move my sprite (kPlayerSpeed = 60.0f):

```
if (ccpDistance(self.position, requestedPosition) < kPlayerSpeed) {
            [self changeState:kStateWalking];
            return;
        }

switch (self.characterState) {
        case kStateWalkingUp:
            self.position = ccp(self.position.x, self.position.y + kPlayerSpeed * deltaTime);
            break;
        case kStateWalkingDown:
            self.position = ccp(self.position.x, self.position.y - kPlayerSpeed * deltaTime);
            break;
        case kStateWalkingLeft:
            self.position = ccp(self.position.x - kPlayerSpeed * deltaTime, self.position.y);
            break;
        case kStateWalkingRight:
            self.position = ccp(self.position.x + kPlayerSpeed * deltaTime, self.position.y);
            break;
        case kStateIdle:
            break;
        default:
            break;

if (ccpDistance(self.position, requestedPosition) < kPlayerSpeed)
```

With this code the player stops near but not exactly on the spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andres, thanks for the reply.

I couldn't quite get your code to work, so using your lead I did a bit more research and came up with this...

```
    float step = kPlayerSpeed * deltaTime;
    float dist = ccpDistance(self.position, requestedPosition);

    if (dist <= step) {
        self.position = requestedPosition;
    } else {
        CGPoint vectorBetweenAB = ccpSub(self.position, requestedPosition);
        CGPoint normVectorBetweenPositionAndEnd = ccpNormalize(vectorBetweenAB);
        CGPoint movementVectorForThisFrame = ccpMult(normVectorBetweenPositionAndEnd, step);
        if (self.position.x > movementVectorForThisFrame.x) {
            movementVectorForThisFrame.x = -movementVectorForThisFrame.x;
        }
        if (self.position.y > movementVectorForThisFrame.y) {
            movementVectorForThisFrame.y = -movementVectorForThisFrame.y;
        }
        self.position = ccpAdd(self.position, movementVectorForThisFrame);
    }
```

Is there a better way to do it than this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would do something along these lines. havent tested it though, im writing from my gfs pc.

```
CGPoint velocity = CGPointZero;
CGPoint delta = ccpSubstract(requestedPosition, self.position);

switch (self.characterState) {
        case kStateWalkingUp:
            velocity= ccp(0, kPlayerSpeed * deltaTime);
            break;
        case kStateWalkingDown:
            velocity = ccp(0,-kPlayerSpeed * deltaTime);
            break;
        case kStateWalkingLeft:
            velocity= ccp(-kPlayerSpeed * deltaTime, 0);
            break;
        case kStateWalkingRight:
            velocity= ccp(kPlayerSpeed * deltaTime, 0);
            break;
        case kStateIdle:
            break;
        default:
            break;
}
CGPoint signsVelocity = ccpNormalize(velocity);
CGPoint absVelocity = ccp( MIN( fabsf(velocity.x), fabsf(delta.x)) , MIN(fabsf(velocity.y), fabsf(velocity.x) );
self.position = ccpAdd(self.position, ccpMult(absVelocity, signsVelocity) );
```